# Odd characters in Unicode String

Tags: delphi, mp3

I'm running into something when it comes to getting an MP3 ID3 v2 implementation going.  I have it working for most part except for this one issue, which probably isn't related to that at all.  Anyhow, I'm using the below code to handle retrieving data of header tags that involve text.

What I'm running into is that (I guess?) I'm encountering Unicode characters in some different strings.  I made the attempt to convert it below, and it works.  But I'm getting $3F as a character ahead of the string and $3F$3F afterwards.  Is there anything I can do to the code below to parse those out or would I have to do it myself?  The files were encoded by ITunes if that helps any.

```
function Id3v2_string(currp: pointer; datasize: integer): string;
{ handles string processing for ID3v2 data }
  const
    IS_TEXT_UNICODE_UNICODE_MASK = $0F;
  var
    outstr: string;
    uscan: integer;
  begin
    outstr := '';
    SetLength(outstr, datasize);
    uscan := IS_TEXT_UNICODE_UNICODE_MASK;
    if IsTextUnicode(currp, datasize, @uscan) then
      outstr := WideCharToString(currp)
    else
      move(currp^, outstr[1], datasize);
    Result := outstr;
  end;
```

Note, I really am not interested in a media library for this since all I'm looking to do is edit ID3 tags and not play files - the implementation is already completed except for a few minor problems like this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on which version of [ID3](http://id3.org/) v2 is being used, text strings may or may not be preceeded with a byte to tell you the actual encoding of the string.  Don't use `IsTextUnicode()` to guess what the encoding is (especially since it can report [false results](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx)).

In ID3 v2 up to v2.3, there is no encoding byte, text is either `ISO-8859-1` or `UCS-2`, and `UCS-2` strings always start with a BOM so you know the byte ordering.  For example:

```
// prior to Delphi 2009 - String is Ansi
function Id3v2_string(currp: Pointer; datasize: Integer): String; 
var
  W: WideString;
  I: Integer;
  Ch: WideChar;
begin 
  Result := '';
  if (datasize >= SizeOf(Word)) and ((PWord(currp)^ = $FEFF) or (PWord(currp)^= $FFFE)) then begin
    // UCS-2 with BOM
    W := WideCharLenToString(PWideChar(Integer(currp) + SizeOf(Word)), (datasize - SizeOf(Word)) div SizeOf(WideChar)); 
    if PWord(currp)^ = $FFFE then begin
      // BE, convert to LE
      for I := 1 to Length(W) do begin
        Ch := W[I];
        W[I] := WideChar(((Word(Ch) and $FF) shl 8) or (Word(Ch) shr 8));
      end;
    end;
  end else begin
    // ISO-8859-1
    I := MultiByteToWideChar(28591, 0, PAnsiChar(currp), datasize, nil, 0);
    if I > 0 then begin
      SetLength(W, I);
      MultiByteToWideChar(28591, 0, PAnsiChar(currp), datasize, PWideChar(W), I);
    end;
  end;
  Result := TrimRight(W);
end;
```

.

```
// Delphi 2009+ - String is Unicode
function Id3v2_string(currp: Pointer; datasize: Integer): String; 
var
  Enc: TEncoding;

  function Convert(P: Pointer; Size: Integer): String;
  var
    Buf: TBytes;
  begin
    SetLength(Buf, Size);
    if Size > 0 then Move(P^, Buf[0], Size);
    Result := Enc.GetString(Buf);
  end;

begin 
  Result := '';
  if (datasize >= SizeOf(Word)) and ((PWord(currp)^ = $FEFF) or (PWord(currp)^ = $FFFE)) then begin
    // UCS-2 with BOM
    if PWord(currp)^ = $FFFE then begin
      // BE
      Enc := TEncoding.BigEndianUnicode;
    end else begin
      // LE
      Enc := TEncoding.Unicode;
    end;
    Result := Convert(PWord(currp)+1, datasize - SizeOf(Word));
  end else begin
    // ISO-8859-1
    Enc := TEncoding.GetEncoding(28591);
    try
      Result := Convert(currp, datasize);
    finally
      Enc.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

ID3 v2.4 switches `UCS-2` to `UTF-16`, and adds support for `UTF-8` and `UTF-16BE` without a BOM, eg:

```
// prior to Delphi 2009 - String is Ansi
function Id3v2_string(currp: Pointer; datasize: Integer; Encoding: Byte): String; 
var
  W: WideString;
  I: Integer;
  Ch: WideChar;
begin 
  Result := '';

  case Encoding of
    $00: begin
      // ISO-8859-1
      I := MultiByteToWideChar(28591, 0, PAnsiChar(currp), datasize, nil, 0);
      if I > 0 then begin
        SetLength(W, I);
        MultiByteToWideChar(28591, 0, PAnsiChar(currp), datasize, PWideChar(W), I);
      end;
    end;
    $01: begin
      // UTF-16 with BOM
      SetString(W, PWideChar(Integer(currp) + SizeOf(Word)), (datasize - SizeOf(Word)) div SizeOf(WideChar));
      if PWord(currp)^ = $FFFE then begin
        // BE, convert to LE
        for I := 1 to Length(W) do begin
          Ch := W[I];
          W[I] := WideChar(((Word(Ch) and $FF) shl 8) or (Word(Ch) shr 8));
        end;
      end;
    end;
    $02: begin
      // UTF-16BE without BOM, convert to LE
      SetString(W, PWideChar(currp), datasize div SizeOf(WideChar));
      for I := 1 to Length(W) do begin
        Ch := W[I];
        W[I] := WideChar(((Word(Ch) and $FF) shl 8) or (Word(Ch) shr 8));
      end;
    end;
    $03: begin
      // UTF-8
      I := MultiByteToWideChar(65001, 0, PAnsiChar(currp), datasize, nil, 0);
      if I > 0 then begin
        SetLength(W, I);
        MultiByteToWideChar(65001, 0, PAnsiChar(currp), datasize, PWideChar(W), I);
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Result := TrimRight(W);
end;
```

.

```
// Delphi 2009+ - String is Unicode
function Id3v2_string(currp: Pointer; datasize: Integer; Encoding: Byte): String; 
var
  Enc: TEncoding;

  function Convert(P: Pointer; Size: Integer): String;
  var
    Buf: TBytes;
  begin
    SetLength(Buf, Size);
    if Size > 0 then Move(P^, Buf[0], Size);
    Result := Enc.GetString(Buf);
  end;

begin 
  Result := '';

  case Encoding of
    $00: begin
      // ISO-8859-1
      Enc := TEncoding.GetEncoding(28591);
      try
        Result := Convert(currp, datasize);
      finally
        Enc.Free;
      end;
    end;
    $01: begin
      // UTF-16 with BOM
      if PWord(currp)^ = $FFFE then begin
        // BE
        Enc := TEncoding.BigEndianUnicode;
      end else begin
        // LE
        Enc := TEncoding.Unicode;
      end;
      Result := Convert(PWord(currp)+1, datasize - SizeOf(Word));
    end;
    $02: begin
      // UTF-16BE without BOM
      Enc := TEncoding.BigEndianUnicode;
      Result := Convert(currp, datasize);
    end;
    $03: begin
      // UTF-8
      Enc := TEncoding.UTF8;
      Result := Convert(currp, datasize);
    end;
  end;
  Result := TrimRight(Result);
end;
```